# how to set gnu find use posix-extended regex type as default

Tags: regex, find

When I use find regex to find .c .cpp .h files 
I have to type

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(c\|cpp\|h)"
```

or use posix-extended regex type

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\.(c|cpp)"
```

The first one have so many '\' and not easy to read.
The second one have to type much more characters. And I am familiar with the second one.

Is there any way to make find use posix-extended regex as default?

I tried to set a alias

```
alias find='find -regextype posix-extended'
```

at my .zshrc file. But it doesn't work because find need put the path on the second argument.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With zsh you have a few options. You can define a global alias:

```
alias -g reg="-regextype posix-extended"
```

This will allow you to type `find ./ reg -regex ".*\.(c|cpp)"` and zsh will do the replacement for you.

The other option is to create a function. Something like:

```
function findr()
{
   dir=$1;
   shift;
   find $dir -regextype posix-extended $*
}
```

You can call it as follows:

```
findr ./ -regex ".*\.(c|cpp)"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. btw, I like the second solution. ^_^